# How do I pass OutDir value in azure-pipelines.yml for the VSBuild task?

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task

This is how the task step looks. I am not able to get the output files into the $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) directory.

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArguments: '/p:OutDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
```

I'm wondering if the msbuildArguments parameter is in the right format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: "/p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
```

Apparently, its msbuildArgs and not msbuildArguments.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.